# Using the C# FaunaDB Client, How do I query an index?

Tags: c#, faunadb

I'm a newbie to FaunaDB. I've been able to add a bunch of documents to a collection using C# like this:

```
Value value = fauna.Query(Create(
    Collection("MyCollection"),
    Obj("data", Encoder.Encode(trans))
    )).Result;
```

Now I need to query individual documents.  So in the FaunaDB Shell, this works great and returns the expected document.

```
Get(
  Match(
    Index("FITID"),
    "2021043000000000000000000000002122180019216600000088701"
  )
)
```

However, when I try to use this in C#, I get an error that I can't figure out how to fix. I can't find any examples specific to what I'm trying to do.

```
Value value = fauna.Query(
        Get(
            Match(
                Index("FITID", "2021043000000000000000000000002122180019216600000088701")
                )
            )
        ).Result;
```

The error I'm getting is

> BadRequest: invalid argument: Database Ref expected, String provided.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Thanks to @eskwayrd for spotting my error.  The correct command is below.

```
Value value = fauna.Query(
        Get(
            Match(
                Index("FITID"), "2021043000000000000000000000002122180019216600000088701"
                )
            )
        ).Result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Index` function returns a reference for the specified index name. In your C# code, you are passing both the index name and the numeric string to `Index`. If you fix the brackets in your query, it should work just fine.

See the second example under "Retrieve Posts": https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/crud?lang=csharp#retrieve

Comment: It's always the most obvious things that I can't see.  Thanks!